# else condition in script with sqlite

Tags: html, sqlite, cordova

I have a script where i need to check the username and password and display a msg using sqlite transaction . the status msg displays the appropriate msg at the right entries but the alert msg for the wrong entries would not show  up . Can this problem be fixed .The script is as follows:

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contact1(id unique, username TEXT NOT NULL, pass TEXT NOT NULL)");
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Contact1(id, username, pass) VALUES (1, 'pp1', '321')");
// tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (2, "logmsg")');
});


$(document).ready(function () // Call function when page is ready for load..

{
 db.transaction(function (tx) {
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Contact1(id, username, pass) VALUES (3, 'pp1', '321')"); 
});

$("#sub").click(function(){
var uname = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Contact1 WHERE username=?', [uname], function (tx, results) {
 var len = results.rows.length, i;
// msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
 //document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
 for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
 //  msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).pass + "</b></p>";
 //document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
 if(results.rows.item(i).username == uname){
// alert("hello");
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Contact1 WHERE  pass=?', [password], function (tx, results) {
           var len = results.rows.length, i;
           msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
           document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
           for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
             msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).username + "</b>==><b>" + results.rows.item(i).pass + "</b></p>";
             document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
           }

         }, null);

         }
 else
  {//wrong username/password case
   msg="<p><b>Please enter the right Username and password"+"</b></p>";
   document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
  }
 }
}, null);

});});});
```

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suganthi pointed out problem, but nevertheless i decided to rewrite your code to fix a problem and to make code better:

```
var db;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contact1(id unique, username TEXT NOT NULL, pass TEXT NOT NULL)");
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Contact1(id, username, pass) VALUES (1, 'pp1', '321')");
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Contact1(id, username, pass) VALUES (3, 'pp1', '321')"); 
    });
}

$("#sub").click(function() {
    var uname = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Contact1 WHERE username = ? AND pass = ?', [uname, password], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            if (len > 0) {
                $('#status').append("<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>");
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).username + "</b>==><b>" + results.rows.item(i).pass + "</b></p>";
                    $('#status').append(msg);
                }
            } else {
                msg = "<p><b>Please enter correct username and password</b></p>";
                $('#status').append(msg);
            }
        }, null);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot , this worked , i just had to remove success msg and place `the navigation URL` there!! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

according to your code
if username is wrong it returns len=0 so it wont enter into else condition.
try this

```
$("#sub").click(function(){
var uname = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Contact1 ', function (tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length, i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
if(results.rows.item(i).username == uname &&results.rows.item(i).pass == password){
// alert("hello");
          msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).username + "</b>==><b>" + results.rows.item(i).pass +      "</b></p>";
         document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
       }
else
{
msg="<p><b>Please enter the right Username and password"+"</b></p>";
document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
}
}
}, null);
```

Comment: it's not good... First of all, "else" will be called as many times, as there are not-accepted rows. Secondly, it's not good to select whole table. Yes, it will work "right here, right now", but what about good code?

Comment: Well, maybe my previous comment can be read as negative, but i only tried to say that it's better not to select whole table and to move error block out of the "for" loop

Comment: @Regent thanku i didn't take it negatively,thanks for guidance.